# python boto3 error: Not authorized to perform assumed role on resource

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to move files from a S3 bucket in one account(source account) to S3 bucket in another account(destination account)
I am using sagemaker notebook so I have a sagemaker role.
I also have a role in my team account  which has full s3 access and fullsagemaker access and in the trust relationship i have given the destination account role arn and sagemaker role arn.
The destination account also has my team role arn and sagemaker role arn in its trust policy.

I am trying to assume my team role and then I will assume the destination role to copy files.

```
    import boto3
    sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
assumed_teamrole_object = sts_client.assume_role(DurationSeconds=1800,
                                                 RoleArn='myteamrole',
                                                 RoleSessionName='test1')
    assumed_destrole_object = sts_client.assume_role(DurationSeconds=1800,
                                                 ExternalId='externalid provided by destination account',
                                                 RoleArn='destination account role',
                                                 RoleSessionName='test2')
```

The first three lines execute fine. when I try to assume the destination role i am getting the error

**An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:sts::role/AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-/SageMaker is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::destinationrole**

Is there something I am missing, what am i doing wrong. Please help.
I dont have any user , it is just roles

Thanks!

Comment: What are the permissions on `AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-` role?

Comment: @Marcin actually there are no permissions on the sagemaker-excution role. Principal": {
        "Service": "sagemaker.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole".  this is all I have in the trust relationship for this role

Comment: @Marcin in the sagemaker execution policy I have"Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that you are missing `sts:AssumeRole` permissions. Your comments indicate that this is the case, as you have only S3 permission for now.

To rectify this, you can add [inline policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html#inline-policies) to `AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole` role, in the form of:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can further limit the `Resource` to only `arn:aws:iam::destinationrole`. But for tests you can try with `*` as `Resource`.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you !! but I have another problem . once i assume the role i am running   response = client.list_objects(Bucket='source bucket')
print(response).  I am getting access deined:ListObjects even though my destionation role has list , get and decrypt permissions. Just  Learnt that the objects are encrypted do I have to add any decrpt permissions on my side? if so where do I need to add. Thanks

Comment: @Anu8 No problem. Please feel free to make new question for the new issue.

Comment: I posted a new question . Thanks!